# Macbook A1181 runs out of memory (RAM) while using XCode 4.2 + iOS simulator - what's the matter and how to solve?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, ios-simulator

When I develop in XCode my Macbook sometimes runs out of memory (once in 6-8 hours of work). I have 4GB of RAM and only 20-100mb are free. I can free 1,5-2GB by restarting XCode and iOS simulator.
Why my computer runs out of memory? Is it due to improper memory management while working in XCode (I'm at beginner level so far)? Or that may be due to other reasons?

Comment: It's because this stuff uses lots of memory. iOS simulator simulates a device with 1 GB of RAM. OWC sells single 8GB chips which is a cheap way to upgrade to 10GB (works with MacBook 7,1).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the cause, but I can tell you something about my symptoms.

I open Activity Monitor and switch the dropdown box to All Processes, then sort by memory use.

```
kernel_task: 1.1 GB
XCode: 510 MB
Opera: 567 MB
Terminal: 328 MB
WindowServer: 228 MB
mds: 202 MB
```

Then a steady decrease for the remaining processes. Total memory use is 6 GB. I have 10 GB free. When I only had 4 GB total, I rebooted my macbook about once or twice per day because memory use got too high. Now I leave it on for weeks and it never goes above 6 GB.

Answer (score -1):

View your RAM usage by:

Open a **Terminal** > type `top` (Hit Enter)

To kill any process, use `kill (processid)` If the process ID is 123, kill the process by `kill 123`